# Risk index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, out

I have seen many posts treating the same question but haven't found  an answer to my specific question.

I am running two loops: -loop 1 takes a bunch of different stocks names and add them to yahoo finance API URL to get their option data. Because each stock has a multitude of options, I am running loop 2 which loops i in range (len(option prices from the internet)) to access each price of each option for each stock.
The whole thing works fine for about 15 stocks then stops with the error message 'list index out of range'

Do anybody has an idea of what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

code:

```
stock_list = ['TREE', 'TSLA', ...]

y = len(stock_list)
while True:
    for x in range(0,y):
        link =("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/" + stock_list[x])
        try:
            optionchain = requests.get(link).json()
        except:
            optionchain = 0

        L = len(optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'])
        while True:
            for i in range (L+1):
                try:
                    arbitrage =  optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'][i]['lastPrice'] - (optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'][i]['strike'] + optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'][i]['ask'])
                except:
                    arbitrage = 0
                if arbitrage > 0:
                    print(stock_list[x])
                    print('pay: ')
                    print(100*optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'][i]['ask'])
                    print('for a risk free profit of: ')
                    print(100*arbitrage)
                    print('info:')
                    print(optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'][i])
                    print(' ')
                else:
                    print(stock_list[x], i, ' No arbitrage')
            break
```

after a while, shell returns:

```
LOXO 13  No arbitrage
LOXO 14  No arbitrage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/owner/Desktop/arbitrage option.py", line 18, in <module>
    L = len(optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but here are some suggestions for approaching your problem.

Notice that the error appears on this line:

```
 L = len(optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'])
```

That gives you a clue about which list and which index might be the problem.

Now, I see two places in that line where you access a list:

```
L = len(optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]['options'][0]['calls'])
                                             ^             ^
                                             |             |
                                             Here          Here
```

So, one of those must be the problem. But which one?

To find out, try splitting the long line into two shorter lines:

```
part_1 = optionchain['optionChain']['result'][0]
L = len(part_1['options'][0]['calls'])
```

Now, when you run it, you'll get a more specific line number for your error.

Let's say, just for example, that the error happens on the first line (`part_1 =`).

Why is the error happening?

One way to learn more would be to print out the list right before you access it:

```
list_1 = optionchain['optionChain']['result']
print('list_1 = ', list_1)
part_1 = list_1[0]
L = len(part_1['options'][0]['calls'])
```

Now, if you see that `list_1 = []`, that will give you a clue about why the error is happening.

Good luck!